# How to report sliding windows with a fixed length in seconds efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of times in seconds such as:

```
L = [ 0.10218048,  1.20851996,  1.46800021,  1.73429061,  2.71525848,
    3.14781922,  3.63637958,  5.11147358,  5.97497864,  6.35469013,
    6.80623747,  6.99571917,  7.65215123,  7.86108352,  8.52988247,
    8.83068894, 10.07690977, 11.53867284, 12.01214112, 12.13307653]
```

For each window of length 2 seconds starting at a second boundary I would like to output a list of all the times that fall within the 2 second window. So for the above example it would be:

```
[0.10218048,  1.20851996,  1.46800021,  1.73429061]
[1.20851996,  1.46800021,  1.73429061, 2.71525848]
[2.71525848, 3.14781922,  3.63637958]
[3.14781922,  3.63637958]
[5.11147358,  5.97497864]
[5.11147358,  5.97497864, 6.35469013, 6.80623747,  6.99571917]
[6.35469013, 6.80623747,  6.99571917, 7.65215123,  7.86108352]
[7.65215123,  7.86108352, 8.52988247, 8.83068894]
[8.52988247, 8.83068894]
[10.07690977]
[10.07690977, 11.5386728]
[11.5386728, 12.01214112, 12.13307653]
[12.01214112, 12.13307653]
```

In general the window length might be different  from 2.

How can you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant increment based on "For each window of length 2 seconds starting at a second boundary" and not overlap. For two second intervals, it's the same, but since you want to vary the length, a one second overlap would be 0-3, 2-5, 4-7, but increment would mean 0-3, 1-4, 2-5. However, it was interesting to figure out solutions for both just in case.

Assuming L is sorted and all elements are positive and the second intervals all start with integers, we can use this method:

```
import math

from collections import defaultdict

L = [ 0.10218048,  1.20851996,  1.46800021,  1.73429061,  2.71525848,
    3.14781922,  3.63637958,  5.11147358,  5.97497864,  6.35469013,
    6.80623747,  6.99571917,  7.65215123,  7.86108352,  8.52988247,
    8.83068894, 10.07690977, 11.53867284, 12.01214112, 12.13307653]

my_ranges = defaultdict(list)

interval_width = 2

for x in L:
    upper_bound = math.ceil(x)
    lower_bound = upper_bound - interval_width
    lower_bound = max(0, lower_bound)
    for y in range(lower_bound, upper_bound):
        my_ranges[y].append(x)

for a in sorted(my_ranges):
    print(my_ranges[a])
```

I don't know if you want to see if there are any empty ranges. But the defaultdict prints out empty ranges if you want, too. Use this line instead of "for a in sorted":

```
for a in range(min(my_ranges), max(my_ranges) + 1):
```

If you wanted the ranges 0-3, 2-5, 4-7, this works:

```
import math

from collections import defaultdict

L = [ 0.10218048,  1.20851996,  1.46800021,  1.73429061,  2.71525848,
    3.14781922,  3.63637958,  5.11147358,  5.97497864,  6.35469013,
    6.80623747,  6.99571917,  7.65215123,  7.86108352,  8.52988247,
    8.83068894, 10.07690977, 11.53867284, 12.01214112, 12.13307653]

interval_width = 2

my_ranges_2 = defaultdict(list)

for x in L:
    definitely_in = (x // (interval_width - 1)) * (interval_width - 1) # lowest multiple of interval_width below x will always be in
    #print("Adding", x, "to", definitely_in)
    my_ranges_2[definitely_in].append(x)
    if x < definitely_in + 1 and definitely_in - interval_width >= 0: # for instance, if x is 2.3 and we have 0,3 2,5 etc. ... we need to catch this duplicate case. I am assuming the window lengths are integers, and if not, we have a lot more to do, because the number may go in more than one array. Perhaps we could have a while loop, incrementing by (interval_width - 1)
        #print("++Adding", x, "to", definitely_in - interval_width + 1)
        my_ranges_2[definitely_in - interval_width + 1].append(x)

for a in sorted(my_ranges_2):
    print(a, my_ranges_2[a])
#    print(my_ranges_2[a])
```

I suspect there are some details I've forgotten, but hopefully you can twiddle interval_width as need be to make sure my code is doing what you hoped and let me know what precisely you need.

Comment: Thank you. You are right I wanted your first solution but both are interesting.

Comment: All the answers are great but yours was first so.. accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution that I can propose is "efficient" in a sense, that it iterates only once through the input data and has no dependencies. The cost, of course, is that it is written in pure python (there might be more optimized code) and that it introduces more tracking variables to prevent reiteration (and thus is less pythonic).

```
def sliding_window(data, duration, start=0, overlap=1):
    result = []

    data_idx = 0
    result_idx = 0

    upper = start + duration
    lower = start
    next_lower = upper - overlap

    # inner helper to pad empty inner-lists up to our insert point and insert
    def pad_and_append(at):
        while len(result) <= at:
            result.append([])

        result[at].append(data[data_idx])

    # iterate through input data
    while data_idx < len(data):
        # is the datum within the current interval?
        if lower <= data[data_idx] < upper:
            pad_and_append(result_idx)

            # is it within the overlap to the next interval?
            if next_lower <= data[data_idx]:
                pad_and_append(result_idx + 1)

            # next datum
            data_idx = data_idx + 1
        else:
            # we captured all items within the interval and
            # the overlap to the next. let's set up the next interval
            result_idx = result_idx + 1
            lower = next_lower
            upper = lower + duration
            next_lower = upper - overlap

    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope I got the question right, you basically want to have you data `L` sliced according to time windows of 2 seconds, with 1 second overlap? Then this might be an option:

```py
import numpy as np

L = [0.10218048,  1.20851996,  1.46800021,  1.73429061,  2.71525848,
    3.14781922,  3.63637958,  5.11147358,  5.97497864,  6.35469013,
    6.80623747,  6.99571917,  7.65215123,  7.86108352,  8.52988247,
    8.83068894, 10.07690977, 11.53867284, 12.01214112, 12.13307653]

L = np.array(L)

lim = []
for i in range(0, int(np.ceil(L[-1])), 1): 
# change 1st range param for other t0
# change 3rd range param for other t step
    lim += [[i,i+2]] # change the '+2' to your desired dt

for l in lim:
    print(L[(L>=l[0]) & (L<l[1])])

# in case you don't need the limits array, just simplify to
# for i in range(0, int(np.ceil(L[-1])), 1):
#    print(L[(L>=i) & (L<i+2)])
```

...prints

```
[0.10218048,  1.20851996,  1.46800021,  1.73429061]
[1.20851996,  1.46800021,  1.73429061, 2.71525848]
[2.71525848, 3.14781922,  3.63637958]
[3.14781922,  3.63637958]
[5.11147358,  5.97497864]
[5.11147358,  5.97497864, 6.35469013, 6.80623747,  6.99571917]
[6.35469013, 6.80623747,  6.99571917, 7.65215123,  7.86108352]
[7.65215123,  7.86108352, 8.52988247, 8.83068894]
[8.52988247, 8.83068894]
[10.07690977]
[10.07690977, 11.5386728]
[11.5386728, 12.01214112, 12.13307653]
[12.01214112, 12.13307653]
```

Note: I'm not sure if this is really efficient since in the loop, the complete array `L` is checked. But I guess `numpy` slicing with conditionals isn't too bad. Would be interesting to see some `timeit` comparison here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution using a simple loop.

```
import math
from collections import defaultdict

L = [ 0.10218048,  1.20851996,  1.46800021,  1.73429061,  2.71525848,
    3.14781922,  3.63637958,  5.11147358,  5.97497864,  6.35469013,
    6.80623747,  6.99571917,  7.65215123,  7.86108352,  8.52988247,
    8.83068894, 10.07690977, 11.53867284, 12.01214112, 12.13307653]

binned = defaultdict(list)
n = 2 #window size
for a in range(math.ceil(max(L))):
    b = a+n
    k = f'{a}:{b}'
    for x in L: #assuming L is sorted
        if x > a:
            if x < b:
                binned[k].append(x)
            else: break

binned


defaultdict(list,
            {'0:2': [0.10218048, 1.20851996, 1.46800021, 1.73429061],
             '1:3': [1.20851996, 1.46800021, 1.73429061, 2.71525848],
             '2:4': [2.71525848, 3.14781922, 3.63637958],
             '3:5': [3.14781922, 3.63637958],
             '4:6': [5.11147358, 5.97497864],
             '5:7': [5.11147358, 5.97497864, 6.35469013, 6.80623747, 6.99571917],
             '6:8': [6.35469013, 6.80623747, 6.99571917, 7.65215123, 7.86108352],
             '7:9': [7.65215123, 7.86108352, 8.52988247, 8.83068894],
             '8:10': [8.52988247, 8.83068894],
             '9:11': [10.07690977],
             '10:12': [10.07690977, 11.53867284],
             '11:13': [11.53867284, 12.01214112, 12.13307653],
             '12:14': [12.01214112, 12.13307653]})
```